# Show that the set is a basis for $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the subspace $S$ in $\Bbb R^3$, $S=\{(a,b,c)\mid a+b=c\}$. Show that the set $B= \{(1,0,1),(1,2,3)\}$ is a basis for $S$.
I've started to set up a matrix, 
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\0&2&0\\1&3&0\end{array}\right]$
   In order to prove linear independence. Is this right? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to set up a matrix. In your place I would show:

1. $S$ is a subspace.
2. $B\subseteq S$.
3. $B$ is linearly independent (directly from the definition).
4. $S \ne \mathbb R^3$.

If $B$ is *not* a basis, then $S$ would have dimension larger than the dimension of the span of $B$, which is $|B|=2$ because $B$ is linearly dependent. But that would contradict the fourth fact.

Answer (score 0):

Showing linear independence is easy, since there are only two vectors. Since they are not scalar multiples of each other, they are linearly independent.

To show that $B$ spans $S$, pick an arbitrary vector in $S$, say $(a, b, a+b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Can you express it as a lineary combination of the two vectors in $B$?